# TypeError (not '_NoValueType') after read_csv upon using drop() and group_by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

upon reading a CSV into pandas, i get a TypeError when perform drop() as well as group_by (in different statements). Any ideas what could be the cause and how i can solve this?

Relevant code:

```
main_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8', sep=None, skipinitialspace=True, dtype='object', na_filter=False, engine='python )

field_list = DataField.objects.filter(datafile=file_id, to_import=False)

list_to_drop=[]
for field in field_list:
    list_to_drop.append(field.fieldname)

if len(list_to_drop) > 0:
    print("About to drop ", len(list_to_drop),"columns: ", list_to_drop)
    main_data = main_data.drop(list_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
```

Debugging data:

```
JSON of the data loaded through read_csv():
{"Timestamp":{"0":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.540","1":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.665","2":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.665","3":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.665","4":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.665","5":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.767","6":"2021-10-05T10:06:59.767","7":"2021-10-05T10:07:04.645","8":"2021-10-05T10:07:04.669","9":"2021-10-05T10:07:04.669"},"Box Serial":{"0":"10-0-13-181 ","1":"10-0-13-181 ","2":"10-0-13-181 ","3":"10-0-13-181 ","4":"10-0-13-181 ","5":"10-0-13-181","6":"10-0-13-181","7":"10-0-13-162 ","8":"10-0-13-162 ","9":"10-0-13-162 "},"Event type":{"0":"Box ","1":"Advertisement","2":"Payment Server","3":"AirFi Sync Socket","4":"Telemetry Service","5":"Initial Battery","6":"Initial Temperature","7":"Box ","8":"Advertisement","9":"Payment Server"},"Status":{"0":"Booting","1":"Starting","2":"Starting","3":"Connected","4":"Starting","5":"43%","6":"20C","7":"Booting","8":"Starting","9":"Starting"},"ID":{"0":"","1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":null,"6":null,"7":"","8":"","9":""},"Unnamed: 5":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null}}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2022-01-06 01:43:55,473 ERROR usecases 7621 6208778240 TRYING TO DROP COLUMNS: ['Unnamed: 5']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/clean/usecases.py", line 114, in drop_non_import_columns
main_data = main_data.drop(list_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
return func(*args, kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4906, in drop
return super().drop(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4150, in drop
obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4186, in _drop_axis
result = self.reindex({axis_name: new_axis})
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 324, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4772, in reindex
return super().reindex(**kwargs)
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4818, in reindex
return self._reindex_axes(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4591, in _reindex_axes
frame = frame._reindex_columns(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4636, in _reindex_columns
return self._reindex_with_indexers(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4883, in _reindex_with_indexers
new_data = new_data.reindex_indexer(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 676, in reindex_indexer
new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 802, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
max_len = max(len(mgr_locs), taker.max() + 1)
File "/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Project1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 40, in _amax
return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'
```

Comment: not sure, but inplace=True shouldn't be used when setting 'main_data = ...' You can set to false or remove the  'main_data = ...' See if one of those options fixes anything.

Comment: inplace = False didn't change the outcome.